# Condition/Paging in listing using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, gridview, conditional-statements, paging

I try to put this condition inside gridview..but it didn't work, but if I if I just use the way as below it worked well. But the problem is if I didn't use Gridview, I can't display the paging and total records. Help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please put the code in your question instead of using images

Comment: alright, noted.

Comment: No point noting it if you aren't going to change it